# Effects of programmatically enabling `Efficiency Mode` for services in Windows 11?

Tags: c, windows, service

Suppose there's a service that's extremely busy during the day but generally idle at night.

Currently Task Manager shows [Efficiency mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/performance-diagnostics/reduce-process-interference-with-task-manager-efficiency-mode/) not enabled

[image: off]

However, applying the code changes below, Task Manager shows `Efficiency mode` enabled

[image: on]

It achieves this mode by applying these methods

- First, the `Efficiency mode` lowers the process priority of background
  tasks so that Windows does not allocate important resources to these
  apps.
- Second, it deploys something called [EcoQoS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/performance-diagnostics/introducing-ecoqos/), which is a Quality of
  Service package that reduces the clock speed for efficient tasks.

To get the `Efficiency mode` to appear in the Task Manager, at a minimum these two are required (through trial and error):

1. Set process priority class to IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS
2. Throttle CPU power with PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_EXECUTION_SPEED

```
#include <windows.h>

// Sets the process priority to IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS.
void set_process_priority()
{
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS);
}

// Enables EcoQos to reduce the clock speed.
void enable_ecoqos()
{
    PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE PowerThrottling = { 0 };
    PowerThrottling.Version = PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_CURRENT_VERSION;
    PowerThrottling.ControlMask = PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_EXECUTION_SPEED;
    PowerThrottling.StateMask = PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_EXECUTION_SPEED;

    SetProcessInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), ProcessPowerThrottling, &PowerThrottling, sizeof(PowerThrottling));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    set_process_priority();
    enable_ecoqos();

    // Process is now running in Efficiency mode...

    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

Will enabling `Efficiency mode` cause degraded performance issues during the day when the service is very busy? (Trying to lower the costs of CPU/Memory usage and make it more [Green Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/sustainable-software/sustainable-software-engineering-sse-and-the-role-and-responsibilities-of-a-sustainable-software-engineer/) friendly).

Are there other [efficiency options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocessinformation) that could be enabled to improve the overall `Efficiency mode`?

Comment: You asked this question yesterday, then because you did not get the answer you deleted it and posted again. Do not do this.

Comment: A process that is idle (GetMessage, WaitFor... etc.) does not use CPU so giving it a lower priority is not going to change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Efficiency Mode reduces the resources allocated to a service and reduces its priority relative to other running services,  switching a process to Efficiency Mode would likely reduce its overall performance.

Whether that matters or not depends on many factors.  If the service is well-designed, it should still perform adequately, however.  The operating system typically defers to services that are in high-demand.

The point of reducing resources is not to achieve performance gains (to those processes having higher priorities); it is to keep the system responsive.  It doesn't make much sense for a background process to consume large amounts of resources if it spends most of its time idle.

I once worked in a company that had a server which polled a SQL Server endpoint ten times per second.  As you can imagine, this is quite a waste if the server sits idle most of the day and does the bulk of its work at night.  I changed the code so that after six seconds of inactivity, it reduced the polling interval to once per second.  After another minute of inactivity, it reduced the polling to once per minute.  If a poll produced a request for activity, the interval went back up to 10 per second.

This had the effect of eliminating most of the wasteful activity, while still making the server responsive during its busy times.

Comment: The service runs pretty much in its own container. Not much else is competing with it, so maybe the performance might reduce a little, but overall still be responsive enough. Thanks for the ideas, I'll have to stress test it.

Comment: It seems that the Task Manager does not "update" the internal state of a process efficiency mode when it is set programmatically. I wrote a small program that enumerates all processes, gets ProcessPowerThrottling values for ControlMask and State Mask, and if they differ from 1, sets the throttling. If I set process efficiency mode with Task Manager, my program sees that these values are already "1", but if I set these values from my program, the task manager does not show these processes as in the efficiency mode, although my program when rerun tells that these proceses have 1s.